# C++: Why is this constexpr not a compile time constant

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constexpr

In the following C++11 code, the last call to arraySize causes a compile error.  Apparently this is because y is a runtime sized array, and the arraySize template parameter N cannot be deduced for y.  I don't understand why x is a compile time sized array, but y ends up runtime sized.  The arraySize template function is taken directly from Scott Meyers' "Effective Modern C++" Item 1.

```
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t arraySize(T(&)[N]) noexcept { return N; }

struct S
{
    char c[10];
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    S* ps = &s;

    char x[arraySize(s.c)];
    char y[arraySize(ps->c)]; // why is y a runtime sized array?

    arraySize(x);
    arraySize(y); // error !?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well I'm stumped... both `s.c` and `ps->c` have the same type, as spited out by `typeid(s.c).name()` or `typeid(ps->c).name()`, i.e. `A10_c` for g++

Comment: To darken it a bit more : if you make `arraySize()`'s parameter a reference-to-const, the following compiles : `char y[arraySize(decltype(ps->c){})];`

Comment: both g++ and clang++ reports `y` is variable length array

Comment: [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f673b33d1a9de1a6) maybe more helpful. `note: read of non-constexpr variable 'ps' is not allowed in a constant expression`

Comment: [Related](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11582) ?

Comment: @Quentin: Well, your replacement is a compile-time constant expression, while the replaced one wasn't. No surprise there.

Comment: @Deduplicator sure, I'll take your word for that, but why does it change behaviour with a pointer ? None of `s` and `ps` are constexpr (and you can't even make them constexpr as the `char` array is uninitialized, says GCC).

Comment: @Quentin: You know `decltype` is an unevaluated context? If you left out the brace-initializer, it probably wouldn't work either. If the compiler really accepts `arraySize(s.c)` as a compile-time constant expression, I don't know why...

Comment: @Deduplicator yes I do, I was referring back to OP's code : the compiler does accept `s.c`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++, the error is not the call to `arraySize(y)`, but the declaration of `y` itself.

The bounds in an array declaration must be a "converted constant expression".

If your compiler accepts the declaration of `y` and later tells you that `y` is an array of runtime bound, it is not a C++ compiler.  There are no arrays of runtime bound in any ratified version of C++, nor the current draft.

The significant difference between `arraySize(s.c)` and `arraySize(ps->c)` is that `ps->c` is the same as `(*ps).c` and the `*` dereference operator requires lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on `ps`, which is not a constant expression (nor is `&s`, see below).  The rest of the expression doesn't involve lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, the array lvalue is directly bound by the reference.

> A constant expression  is either a glvalue core constant expression whose value refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant expression whose value is an object where, for that object and its subobjects:
>
> - each non-static data member of reference type refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant
>     expression, and
> - **if  the  object  or  subobject  is  of  pointer  type,  it  contains  the  address  of  an  object  with  static  storage duration, the address past the end of such an object (5.7), the address of a function, or a null pointer value.**
>
> An entity is a permitted result of a constant expression if it is an object with static storage duration that is either not a temporary object or is a temporary object whose value satisﬁes the above constraints, or it is a
>   function.

Clearly `ps` contains the address of an object with automatic storage duration, so it cannot be declared `constexpr`.  But everything should start working if you change `S s; S* ps = &s;` to `static S s; constexpr S* ps = &s;`

(On the other hand, you'd think that the parameter to `arraySize(s.c)` is not a constant expression either, since it is a reference and not to an object of static storage duration)

Comment: "If your compiler accepts the declaration of y and later tells you that y is an array of runtime bound, it is not a C++ compiler."  — This part is not true, a conforming implementation (compiler) is expressly permitted to "accept" (i.e. compile and/or execute) ill-formed input by the way of extensions, see e.g. 1.4/8 in the N4296 draft. The implementation **is** required to issue a diagnostic in this case, and GCC and clang do fail to issue a warning for variable-length arrays unless the -pedantic option is added to the invocation.